# (Feed-Forward) Neural Networks keep converging to mean

Tags: r, neural-networks, nnet

I'm having an interesting dilemma with the `neuralnet` and `nnet` packages in `R`.  I recently tried a series of feed-forward neural networks giving each the same data sets and every single time, no matter how I tweak the algorithms, hidden layers, neuron sizes, maximum iterations or error thresholds, both functions keep converging their predictions to approximately the mean of whatever they are training on.

A linear regression does way better for each series in terms of fit, and both of these packages seem to do a better job fitting random data from the `rnorm` function than real data.  In regards to the mathematics of the problem, what could be causing this and how should I resolve?  I have sample code below and can paste a sample dataset below if requested.  Thanks!

```
model6 <- neuralnet(
    target ~ 1 + majorholiday + mon + sat + sun + thu + tue + wed + tickets + l1_target + l7_target, data = data_nn
    ,algorithm = "rprop+", hidden = c(8), stepmax = 500000
    ,err.fct = "sse", threshold = 0.01, lifesign = "full", lifesign.step = 100
    , linear.output= T)
```

**EDIT**

A user requested I paste some data.  Here is one set below and I just tried the same code again prior to uploading and the same thing happens, converges to the mean of `target` at about 17.45

```
    row.names   target  majorholiday    mon sat sun thu tue wed backtickets l1_target   l7_target
1   8   18.976573088    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   13806   18.114001584    36.521334684
2   9   20.701716096    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   15308   18.976573088    35.477867979
3   10  25.014573616    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   13439   20.701716096    28.173601042
4   11  15.706877377    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   11283   25.014573616    27.602288128
5   12  19.633596721    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   12272   15.706877377    13.801144064
6   13  20.049395337    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   9528    19.633596721    32.777717152
7   14  21.720178282    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   13747   20.049395337    18.114001584
8   15  23.390961226    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   15277   21.720178282    18.976573088
9   16  16.707829447    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   16058   23.390961226    20.701716096
10  17  15.872437975    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   14218   16.707829447    25.014573616
11  18  23.295531996    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   11249   15.872437975    15.706877377
12  19  22.363710716    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   13993   23.295531996    19.633596721
13  20  24.227353276    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   13402   22.363710716    20.049395337
14  21  20.500068156    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   14244   24.227353276    21.720178282
15  22  26.090995836    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   14502   20.500068156    23.390961226
16  23  18.636425597    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   16296   26.090995836    16.707829447
17  24  15.840961757    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   13694   18.636425597    15.872437975
18  25  20.650050308    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   10774   15.840961757    23.295531996
19  26  13.467424114    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   12348   20.650050308    22.363710716
20  27  19.752222033    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   12936   13.467424114    24.227353276
21  28  27.832676502    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   14342   19.752222033    20.500068156
22  29  18.854393759    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   14390   27.832676502    26.090995836
23  30  10.773939291    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   16724   18.854393759    18.636425597
24  31  12.569595839    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   14091   10.773939291    15.840961757
25  32  28.153882107    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   11250   12.569595839    20.650050308
26  33  24.400031160    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   12803   28.153882107    13.467424114
27  34  21.584642949    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   13318   24.400031160    19.752222033
28  35  27.215419370    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   14193   21.584642949    27.832676502
29  36  21.584642949    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   14312   27.215419370    18.854393759
30  37  15.015403791    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   16445   21.584642949    10.773939291
31  38  26.276956633    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   13753   15.015403791    12.569595839
32  39  15.139500902    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   11619   26.276956633    28.153882107
33  40  12.467824272    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   14006   15.139500902    24.400031160
34  41  21.373413039    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   14098   12.467824272    21.584642949
35  42  8.015029889 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   14462   21.373413039    27.215419370
36  43  16.030059779    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   15367   8.015029889 21.584642949
37  44  19.592295285    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   17868   16.030059779    15.015403791
38  45  18.701736409    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   15052   19.592295285    26.276956633
39  46  16.002499062    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   10035   18.701736409    15.139500902
40  47  16.943822536    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   13708   16.002499062    12.467824272
41  48  11.295881691    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   13463   16.943822536    21.373413039
42  49  19.767792959    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   13998   11.295881691    8.015029889
43  50  19.767792959    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   14745   19.767792959    16.030059779
44  51  16.943822536    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   16156   19.767792959    19.592295285
45  52  14.119852113    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   13552   16.943822536    18.701736409
46  53  22.869570079    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   11554   14.119852113    16.002499062
47  54  10.481886286    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   13437   22.869570079    16.943822536
48  55  19.057975066    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   14076   10.481886286    11.295881691
49  56  20.010873819    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   14567   19.057975066    19.767792959
50  57  9.528987533 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   14277   20.010873819    19.767792959
51  58  21.916671326    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   16545   9.528987533 16.943822536
52  59  11.000000000    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   15599   21.916671326    14.119852113
53  60  17.000000000    0   0   0   0   1   0   1   17463   11.000000000    22.869570079
54  61  10.000000000    0   0   0   0   0   1   1   17935   17.000000000    10.481886286
55  62  20.000000000    0   0   0   1   0   0   1   18357   10.000000000    19.057975066
56  63  19.000000000    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   19246   20.000000000    20.010873819
57  64  17.000000000    0   1   0   0   0   0   1   21234   19.000000000    9.528987533
58  65  11.000000000    0   0   1   0   0   0   1   18493   17.000000000    21.916671326
59  66  9.000000000 1   0   0   0   0   0   1   15315   11.000000000    11.000000000
60  67  22.000000000    0   0   0   0   1   0   1   17841   9.000000000 17.000000000
61  68  9.000000000 0   0   0   0   0   1   1   18312   22.000000000    10.000000000
62  69  11.000000000    0   0   0   1   0   0   1   17880   9.000000000 20.000000000
63  70  5.000000000 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   19371   11.000000000    19.000000000
64  71  15.000000000    0   1   0   0   0   0   1   21696   5.000000000 17.000000000
65  72  12.000000000    0   0   1   0   0   0   1   18829   15.000000000    11.000000000
66  73  10.000000000    1   0   0   0   0   0   1   14749   12.000000000    9.000000000
67  74  15.000000000    0   0   0   0   1   0   1   17928   10.000000000    22.000000000
68  75  7.000000000 0   0   0   0   0   1   1   18254   15.000000000    9.000000000
```

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc it's a feed-forward and it has 1 hidden layer with 8 neurons predicting a numerical variable `target`.  It has no "activation function" but it's using Sum-Squared-Error as it's error function to minimize.  The algorithm is resilient back-propagation but no matter how I change any of these values I still get the mean.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc my bad you're right the activation function is linear I was only thinking in classification terms.  But there's no way the mean is the global minimum because I tried running this with a linear regression and the sum of squared residuals is way smaller.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc so in R you can display your problem like a formula so `target` ~ 1 + ... means I have my variable target in the dataset above modeled by a constant (1) and all those other variables as inputs.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc yes you're right and I can over-write that default by setting `linear.output = T` and it's also written that way in the documentation.  If I make `linear.output = F` then I would pass it through some logistic or hyperbolic-tangent activation function...wouldn't do that here though because I'm trying to predict a numeric variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is identified in chat discussion. The logistic function in the hidden layer is saturated with large input values.

It is recommended to normalize the input values to [-1,1] range as standard NN practice.

Question owner acknowledged that it resolved his problem.

Answer (score 6):

(1) Some of your predictors are on wildly different scales. Most texts (e.g., Ripley, 96; Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman 08) recommend preprocessing the predictors by scaling the range to [0,1].

(2) In my experience, fit is very sensitive to tuning parameter values. Again, most authors recommend searching over an extensive grid of values for (a) the size of the hidden layer and (b) the value of weight decay, the smoothing parameter.

Here is some code that uses package nnet for fitting the network and package caret for training the tuning parameters. I also use doMC to parallelize the training over 24 cores on my machine but you should adjust the ''cores = '' value to however many you have on yours. Also, I think doMC doesn't work on Windows so you might have to delete those two lines if you are running windows.

```
library(caret)
library(nnet)
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores = 24)
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", 
                     number = 10)
nnet_grid <- expand.grid(.decay = 10^seq(-5, 1, .25), 
                         .size = c(1, 2, 4, 8, 16))
nnfit <- train(form = target ~ majorholiday + mon + sat + sun + thu + tue + wed + backtickets + l1_target + l7_target,
               data = dat,
               method = 'nnet', 
               MaxNWts = 4000,
               maxit = 4000,
               preProcess = "range",
               trControl = ctrl, 
               tuneGrid = nnet_grid,
               linout = TRUE) 

ps <- predict(nnfit, dat)
```

The best combination of size and decay I get are size = 1 and decay = 10^(.5). What this tells me is that, according to cross-validated test error, the winning combination is one with the smallest size (i.e., the least number of additional parameters) and a very large weight decay value (i.e., the most smoothing). This points to a simple, rather than a complex solution for this data, where ``simple'' here means closer to linear.

Remember that the feed forward neural net with one hidden layer is a nonlinear generalization of linear regression. With zero hidden units, it is equivalent. Thus, it makes sense that a multiple regression, which essentially models the response surface with a hyperplane in your covariate space, also fit well.

In any case, preprocessing the predictors by scaling them to [0,1] seems to solve your mean-only predicted values problem.

Comment: thanks for the reply this is actually a great answer but I already promised the points to another person via the chat...sorry your answer works too I wish I could give you both the credit :/

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before.

I think in the general case the average problem can happen when.

1. Your final hidden layer blew up and all values are activated all the time. When all the values are 1 or 0 all the time. You basically just have the bias unit doing the lifting. And the bias unit can only predict the average at best. This can be cuased by wrong weight initialization or a step size that is too big. Is your `stepsize` = 50000?
   `
2. Using `cross-entropy` or `squared error` loss, when you should be using `softmax`

Comment: thanks for the response.  I don't have a minimum stepsize, `stepmax` just says I want a maximum of 500,000 iterations but the model will go until it coverges or hits that and it always takes about 40+ steps to hit the mean.  I also can't use the `softmax` function because my `target` variable is numeric.